# When creating django model, it posts the data, but does not save it in database

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I can create model objects through admin panel. But I want it to be created on website. The code below allows me to enter values of a model, and when I submit it, it redirects to the written url, which happens after `form.save`. This is the message from server `"POST /taskcreate HTTP/1.1" 302 0`. But there is no changes in database. How to solve this issue? Any thoughts... Thanks

models.py

```
class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date_published', auto_now_add = True)
    cost = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)
```

forms.py

```
class TaskCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'cost')
```

views.py

```
def TaskCreateView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = TaskCreateForm()
    return render(request, 'employer/create_task.html')
```

Comment: can you show ur html form for the same

Comment: Are you sure your form passes the `is_valid` check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use **ModelForm** you just need to write `form.save()` method right after `if is_valid()` if case.  In your case, you are missing **curly brackets after save**.

```
def TaskCreateView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save() # here you were missing curly brackets
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = TaskCreateForm()
    return render(request, 'employer/create_task.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't actually *call* the save method.

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return redirect('home')
```